# Reload QR Code Scan on HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

I am using the solution proposed by Mike Taulty on HoloLens to decode a `QR Code`. When I scan it, I change the scene to the next one, but if the result is not correct, I go back to the previous scene. The method that decodes the `QR Code` is as follows:

```
bool scanned = false;
MediaFrameQrProcessing.Wrappers.ZXingQrCodeScanner.ScanFirstCameraForQrCode(
    result =>
    {
      UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
      {
        if(result != null && !scanned)
        {
            scanned = true;
            DisableQrSight();
            Result.name = result;
            captureAudioSource.Play();
            StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
        }
      }, 
      false);
    },
    null);
```

I use a `bool` variable in order to control that the previous method is executed once. I have debugged and I have found that, when this method is executed for a second time, a exception is produced.

If someone had this problem and could solve it or know how to deal with it, I would thank so much. Also, any idea could help.

Thanks in advance,
Cristian.

Comment: What is the exception that is produced?

Comment: Hi @Jethro, thank you for responding to my problem. I already solved it changing the logic of the scene. If someone wants to know how I did it, contact me.

Comment: Hi @CrisGmz, I'm interested in to replicate the QR scanning functionality on my own, but in the Hololens emulator as I don't have a real device, does Mike Taulty's solution work in the emulator? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @saman0suke. As far as I know, the Mike Taulty's solution does not work in the emulator. The only solution that I could give you if you don't have the device would be trying [QR Scan in UWP with USB2.0 Webcam and Kinect 2](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2966/qr-scan-in-uwp-with-usb2-0-webcam-and-kinect-2#latest). I have not tested it but it is said that it works in the emulator. I hope it can help you.